# Pandas/Python - Excel Data Manipulation

Tags: python, arrays, string, excel, pandas

So, relatively new to Python/Pandas but I do have a couple of years of programming under my belt but it's mainly with Java/C++ so nothing like a scripting language like Python.

My new job has me doing some scripting stuff and it's been pretty basic so far so I decided to try and do more and hopefully show my bosses that I am driven and willing to work hard and move up on the ladder and with that I wanted to make one of our data analysis tasks more efficient, by using Pandas to remove redundancies from an excel sheet. However, the redundancies that I'm trying to "parse" for is a substring within a "description" excel column.

```
import pandas as pd
xlsx = pd.ExcelFile('Filename.xlsx')
sheet1 = xlsx.parse(0)
```

So I read the excel file and parsed it into a data frame. I realized it may be easier to just use the read_csv instead, but by the time I thought about it, I was already committed into following through with excel. (Unless the transition isn't difficult, i'm just confused how I could export as a comma delimited when the original file is space delimited)

Here is how the data is kind of laid out:

```
ID       Count#1       Count#2        Count#3          Description
1A42H4      1             0              2             Blahblah JIG GN=TRAC Blah Blah
242JB4      0             0              2             Blahblah JIG GN=SMOOTH Blah Blah  
3MIVJ2      2             0              2             Blahblah JIG GN=TRAC Blah Blah
4JAXI3      1             0              3             BlahBlah JIG GN=TRAC Blah Blah
```

So I want to parse this datasheet and look for any redundant `GN=TRAC`(just similar GN=something) and then organize them all together into a separate datasheet. So I made an array of just the description column

```
   `array = dataframe.description`
```

Then, I decided to use a string split on "JIG", because I didn't need that, and it was constant for all rows. so

```
  `Splits = array.str.split('JIG')`
```

Because of that I was left with the

```
 `array[0] = Blahblah, 
  GN=TRAC Blah Blah`
```

and now I wanted to isolate it again for

```
GN=TRAC
```

so I added them all into an array

```
`array2[n] = splits[n][1]`
```

again and did another split `splits2 = array2.str.split(' ')` to reorganize the

```
GN=TRAC
```

as the first position and isolate by itself. I realize I could have just did a space delimited on the original description, but there are different amounts of words so I wouldn't be able to parse or compare since the location for the

```
GN=TRAC
```

are all varying.

Now to iterate and compare them all I came up with this little function.

```
counter = 0
temp = counter + 1
print(sheet1.iloc[counter])
while counter <= len(sheet1):
    if splits2[counter][0] == splits2[temp][0]:
        print(sheet1.iloc[temp])
        temp += 1
    if splits2[counter][0] != splits2[temp][0]:
        temp += 1
counter += 1
```

But I can't get past here. I'm able to iterate through and find all of the redundant rows with the first row `GN=TRAC` value, but the counter isn't iterating for the next row for comparison. I've tried a couple of variations, but I was hoping for a new pair of eyes. Based off of that table above, it would then go to the second row and find all the rows that match the `GN=SMOOTH` and on and on until the `counter` reaches the final iterated row.

Lastly, I was hoping I could get some help on the best way to organize them together based on the `GN=?` into an output.xlsx. I realize that there is the `writer` and `to_excel` but I'm just not sure how I would use that then. I read through the documentation as much as I can and it doesn't seem like there is a function that I could use to help me which is why it's pretty complicated (do let me know how to make it more efficient and scriptable though, I can generalize it later)

p.s. Is there also a way to write to the excel but in descending order of `Count#1`?

Comment: Are you sure you correctly copied down the indentation on that while loop? Indentation is part of the syntax in Python [see here](http://www.diveintopython.net/getting_to_know_python/indenting_code.html)

Comment: @lerenard thanks for catching that, that was just a copying mistake on my part onto SO. The indents are fine when I actually run it.

Comment: you still have the `counter += 1` part outside the indentation. That loop will never end.

Comment: The curious part is that it does end, and the counter value never actually increases. Only the temp value increases... which doesn't really make sense to me O.o

Comment: post an [SSCE](http://sscce.org/)

Answer (score 0):

You could try

`sheet1['GN'] = sheet1.Description.apply(lambda x: x.split('JIG')[1].split()[0])`

which should insert a new column with the name `GN` into your DataFrame with the appropriate `GN=*` values.

To sort the DataFrame from any particular column you can sort the DataFrame by `sheet1.sort('GN')`.

To save the DataFrame to an excel file you can use `sheet1.to_excel('filename')`. You can chain this with the above `sort` function to write a file sorted by a particular column.